# laravel 5.6 fill() tries to update table using non-existent 'id' field

Tags: laravel, eloquent

this is my model

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class OrganizationProfile extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
    'logo', 
    'number_of_employees', 
    'siup', 'npwp', 'year_established', 'join_ppsdm', 'industry_sector',
    'address', 'city', 'province', 'country', 
    'postal_code',
    'organization_phone', 
    'organization_email'
];
}
```

migration table for OrganizationProfile

```
Schema::create('organization_profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedInteger('organization_id');
        $table->primary('organization_id');
        $table->foreign('organization_id')->references('id')->on('organizations')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('logo')->nullable();
        $table->integer('number_of_employees')->nullable();
        $table->string('siup')->nullable();
        $table->string('npwp')->nullable();
        $table->integer('year_established')->nullable();
        $table->integer('join_ppsdm')->nullable();
        $table->string('industry_sector')->nullable();
        $table->text('address')->nullable();
        $table->string('city')->nullable();
        $table->string('province')->nullable();
        $table->string('country')->nullable();
        $table->string('postal_code')->nullable();
        $table->string('organization_phone')->nullable();
        $table->string('organization_email')->nullable();
        $table->text('meta')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

and this in my controller:

```
$org = OrganizationProfile::where('organization_id', $id)->first();

    if ($org == null) {
        $org = new OrganizationProfile();
        $org->organization_id = $id;
    } 
    $org->fill($request->input())->save();
```

this is the error:
[image]

eloquent tries to update the changed values using 'id' as a reference. i don't have 'id' field, i have a 'organization_id' as primary and foreign key. this error don't show up if i don't change any values listed in $fillable.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eloquent will assume that each table has a primary key column named `id`. You can override it with `$primaryKey` like this:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class OrganizationProfile extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'organization_id';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the model to:

```
  <?php
    namespace App;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class OrganizationProfile extends Model
    {
        protected $primaryKey = 'organization_id';

        protected $fillable = [
        'logo', 
        'number_of_employees', 
        'siup', 'npwp', 'year_established', 'join_ppsdm', 'industry_sector',
        'address', 'city', 'province', 'country', 
        'postal_code',
        'organization_phone', 
        'organization_email'
    ];
    }
```

if you want to disable incrementing. just add code below in your model

```
public $incrementing = false;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this;

`$org->fill($request->except('id'))->save();`

Comment: this does not work since the table is still using 'id' to find the record although the 'id' field is not being updated